# Exclude Profile ID in page count?

Tags: php, redirect, count

I'm using a page count to control the number of times a user can view a page before being redirected. the page is profile.php and if a user clicks on a users profile this takes them to profile.php with the extension id=1 or id=8 etc.

at the moment this script is placed in profile.php and it works fine, it limits the number of profiles a user can view. but i want to exclude a few profiles. is this possible?

I'm new and a beginner to php so if someone could please show me that would really help.

Please and thank you.

```
<?php 

!session_id() ? session_start() : null;
if(!isset($_SESSION['page_access_count'])){
    $_SESSION['page_access_count'] = 1;
}elseif($_SESSION['page_access_count'] >= 6){
    // redirect to signup page
    header('Location: limit.php');
    exit;
}

    // increase the page access session value
    $_SESSION['page_access_count']++;


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement.

```
if(on profile foo){
   do bar
}
else {
   count++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Use an if statement. Looks like you're familiar with them, and you've already got some decent understanding of PHP, so maybe I'm missing something?

Specifically, for ease of maintenance, I'd do:

```
$free_profiles = array(1,8,12,14,96); // array of profile IDs to exclude

if (! in_array($_GET['id'], $free_profiles)) {
  $_SESSION['page_access_count']++;
}
```

Comment: thanks this works when i user the values you set like 1, 2, 5, 8 etc but it doesnt work on profile numbers 99999, 99998, 99997, 99996, 99995, 99994, 99993. is this because there larger values?

Comment: @JohnSimmons No. And those numbers aren't particularly large. I can't think of any reason, other than mistakes. Try adding `var_dump($_GET['id']);` and `var_dump($free_profiles);` at the bottom to be able to compare the values. Also, maybe `var_dump('incrementing page count');` inside my `if` statement -- so you know for sure when it's occurring.

Comment: ok i've added all of that and still only profiles with single digits such as 1, 2, 4 or 5, are working. the rest are just causing the count script to place the block. i've emptied cache and cant figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Right. That wasn't supposed to fix anything -- just print out some values so you could compare. Sorry, but you're on your own at this point. I've tested the code an it works. It works for you with smaller numbers. I still think you're making a mistake (like 9999 instead of 99999 or something), so you're on your own to use debug statements and try to figure something out.